# in-App-purchase not available in Capabilities in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, capability

i created an provisioning file for my app. I checked In-App-Purchase on. If I click in Xcode on 'Signing & Capabilities' it list included capabilities, and in-App-Purchase too. Bundle-ID is the same. 
If i want to add the capability 'In-App-Purchase', it is not available in the list. What did I forget to do or to check?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a paid Apple Membership associated with the project? If you do not the "In App Purchase" capability will not be shown as an option. Capabilities are shown based on your program membership with Apple.

Please see the following [resource](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6).

Comment: Yes, of course. My membership is paid. The needed entries and filled forms under 'Agreements, tax, and banking overview' in AppStoreConnect are fine. => I called Apple Dev Support. It seems there is something wrong with my account. They will check and come back with feedback.

Comment: My Account had the wrong settings. Apple changed this and now all looks fine as expected. Thank you for your helpful advice! :-)