# No IAP Capability for Independent WatchOS App in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, watchos, xcode13

I can't find the In App Purchase capability in Xcode to add to my Independent WatchOS App (i.e. no iOS app). The bundle ID has the capability naturally (I enabled it when registering it) but the option is not in Xcode (only Apple Pay). How do I add IAP to my watch app now? Without a 3rd party extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143159/in-app-purchase-not-available-in-capabilities-in-xcode-11?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add an In-App Purchase (IAP) capability in Xcode to an independent watchOS app. However, your watch app must target **watchOS 6.2** or later.

You can setup your specific IAP's in App Store Connect to get their product ID's.

Comment: So I can make a watchOS app (6.2 or later) that has working IAP without needing IAP capability in Xcode? (Product ID's setup in App Store Connect, of course)

Comment: Yep! I double checked my own published watchOS app that has in-app purchases and it does not require any Xcode capability for IAP.

Comment: Can I get a code example? I still can't get my IAPs do show up on mine...Using this tutorial [https://blckbirds.com/post/how-to-use-in-app-purchases-in-swiftui-apps/](https://blckbirds.com/post/how-to-use-in-app-purchases-in-swiftui-apps/)